# Are there equivalents to "this" for static variables in c#

Tags: c#, static, this

I was wondering if I can make my code clearer by indicating one variable is a static class variable. If it wasn't static I could use this.variableName, and everyone would look at it and immediately know that.

I know I could adopt a naming convention like s_variableName, but that seems a little odd to me and increases the learning curve of the code.

Is there an equivalent of "this" for static variables?

Comment: if you have to use a static class variable, you should think twice, if there's not a design flaw somewhere

Comment: @scoregraphic I know, I thought three times :)

Comment: Static class variables are perfectly fine, for example a singleton implementation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Qualify it with the type name:

```
TypeName.staticVariableName
```